# Having trouble using storybook 6.5.16 with Angular 14+

Tags: storybook, angular14, angular-storybook

I am using 6.5.16 version of storybook to generate component documentation for angular. While we are able to generate `Docs` for angular component the `Canvas` doesn't render the component (though on inspection we can see the component selector).

Further investigation revealed that storybook needs webpack5 for versions above 6. Angular supports only webpack4.
Ref **Github Issue** [#21336](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21336#issuecomment-1453441654)

Hence we have 2 questions.

1. Is there a way we can make storybook support angular by setting `builder` within `preview.js` as `webpack4` for angular 14+ versions.

the alternative option would be

2. Making angular app compatible with Webpack 5. Are there any possibilities that can be explored to make Angular 14+ versions to support Webpack5.

Please share the thoughts.